# How to count number of observations/rows within each group

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a huge unbalanced panel data. I want to count number of rows within each group. For example, I have the following data:

```
data ={{AA,1,10},{AA,2,20},{CC,3,30},{CC,4,40},{CC,5,50},{CC,6,60},{CC,7,70},{DD,8,80},   
        {DD,9,90},{DD,10,100}};
```

I want to calculate number of rows within each group without using do loop. My result should be

```
result={{AA,2},{CC,5},{DD,3}};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the test case in @rhermans' answer, an approach based on `Gather` is more than twice as fast as `Tally`:

```
ClearAll[tllyF];
tllyF = {#[[1]], Length@#} & /@ Gather[#[[All, 1]]] &;

data1 = Table[{RandomChoice[{AA, BB, CC, DD}], RandomInteger[10], 
    RandomInteger[10]}, {1000000}];

First[Timing[res0 = Tally[data1[[All, 1]]]]]
(* 0.234375 *)
First[Timing[res1 = (tllyF@data1)]]
(* 0.078125 *)
res0 == res1
(* True *)


data2 = Table[{RandomChoice[{AA, BB, CC, DD}], RandomInteger[10], 
    RandomInteger[10]}, {10000000}];
First[Timing[res0 = Tally[data2[[All, 1]]]]]
(* 2.53125 *)
First[Timing[res1 = (tllyF@data2)]]
(* 0.93750 *)
res0 == res1
(* True *)
```

Comment: Kguler, thanks for your time and reply.

Comment: @rka, please see [Help Center > Asking](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 10):

Without a `Do` loop

```
Tally[First /@ data]
```

> `{{AA, 2}, {CC, 5}, {DD, 3}}`

or for speed

```
Tally[data[[All, 1]]]
```

> `{{AA, 2}, {CC, 5}, {DD, 3}}`

**EDIT:**

Testing for a bigger set of data:

```
data2 =  Table[{RandomChoice[{AA, BB, CC, DD}], RandomInteger[10],RandomInteger[10]}, {10000000}];
```

We get:

```
First@Timing@Tally[data2[[All, 1]]]
```

> 2.683217

```
First@Timing@Tally[First@Transpose[data2]]
```

> 3.416422

```
First@Timing@Tally[First /@ data2]
```

> 5.304034

So mapping is the slowest as suggested by @Artes

Comment: You are correct, I did misread, sorry. :) Will edit then.

Comment: See answer by @kguler for a faster solution (+1).

Answer (score 4):

This should be faster than mapping `First`:

```
Tally[ First @ Transpose[data]]
```

> ```
> {{AA, 2}, {CC, 5}, {DD, 3}}
> ```

One can use also **new  functions** (in *version 10*) like `Count`, `CountsBy` and `GroupBy`  to get similar results, e.g. :

```
CountsBy[ data, First]
```

> ```
> <|AA -> 2, CC -> 5, DD -> 3|>
> ```

If the format is crucial we can do this

```
  List @@@ Normal @ CountsBy[ data, First]
```

> ```
> {{AA, 2}, {CC, 5}, {DD, 3}}
> ```

Comment: For speed is better `Tally[data2[[All, 1]]]`

Comment: @rhermans Have you really done a reliable test? I'm sure `Transpose` is better.

Comment: I added my test in my answer, probably its not reliable, please do tell me.

Comment: First answer gives me the results in my format. Others don't. Therefore, I think first is better.

Comment: @rka I provided results in the desired format, I guess `CountsBy` can be advantageous in various cases.

Comment: @Artes Thank you for taking time to answer my question.

Comment: @rhermans You have a slightly better performance for `Tally[data2[[All, 1]]]` than `Tally[First@Transpose[data2]]` because `data2` is a very special list i.e. a long list of lists of length `3`. If small lists are of comparable lenghts to a big list, `Transpose` will appear much better.